# Having trouble hiding menu when resizing and when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {  
#side-menu {  
        display: none;  
    }  
    button {  
        display: block;  
    }  
}
```

to hide my side menu and display a button when I resize window. I also want to show and hide menu when the button is pressed. To do that I'm using this code:

```
function showMenu() {
  var sideMenu = document.getElementById("side-menu");
  if (sideMenu.style.display === "none") {
    sideMenu.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else {
    sideMenu.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

When I hide with button the menu does not reappear when I resize window. I believe this is happening because the javaScript changes the primary style to display: none, so once it's out of range it applies the primary style. Now it's display: none so it doesn't appear again. How can I get it to work how I intend it to? Also, it takes two clicks to show menu for some reason.

```
<ul id="side-menu"> 
  <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example4</a></li>
</ul>
```

html just in case you need it.

Comment: are you talking about hamburger menu?

Comment: Your issue is that `sideMenu.style.display === "none"` is false the first time you test it, because inline style is not know until assigned.

Comment: run my snippet, I included an additional media query to handle button visibility on screens bigger than 850px - Click full page to test responsiveness.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma you have to press the button twice because of my comment.

Comment: @dev7 check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/daubs9vt/. I guess you are expecting something like this.

Comment: Yesss thanks ksa. I think it was the !important property I was missing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @dev7, you are welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//swap none with block to fix double button press
function showMenu() {
  var sideMenu = document.getElementById("side-menu");
  if (sideMenu.style.display === "block") {
    sideMenu.style.display = "none";
  } 
  else {
    sideMenu.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```
/* add this to fix menu show*/
@media screen and (min-width: 850px) {  
#side-menu {  
        display: block !important;  
    }  
    button {  
        display: none;  
    }  
}
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {  
#side-menu {  
        display: none;  
    }  
    button {  
        display: block;  
    }  
}
```

```
<div id="side-menu">
<ul> 
  <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button onclick="showMenu()">click me</button>
```

Thanks ksa and StackSlave

Comment: Traditionally on StackOverflow, if a user has helped solve your problem, a better way to show gratitude for the time we put into providing an answer would be marking the answer as correct, or upvoting useful ones.  :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't quite get the answer right so I was not sure to mark you as having the right answer. The people that commented actually were the ones to help me, but can't mark a comment as an answer as far as I know. I tried to up vote you because you tried, but it said I was too new to up vote :\

Comment: !important is not necessary for your code unless you're overriding a previous declaration and is actually bad practice, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. That is the only difference between our answers. Either way, glad your issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You must check if the display === "block" first to fix the multiple click issue.

Included media query to manage window width that is greater than 850px to show list and hide button.

EDIT: updated snippet to use the list provided in the original question.

```js
function showMenu() {
  var sideMenu = document.getElementById("side-menu");
  if (sideMenu.style.display === "block") {
    sideMenu.style.display = "none";
  } 
  else {
    sideMenu.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 850px) {  
#side-menu {  
        display: block;  
    }  
    button {  
        display: none;  
    }  
}


@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {  
#side-menu {  
        display: none;  
    }  
    button {  
        display: block;  
    }  
}
```

```html
<div id="side-menu">
<ul> 
  <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">example4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button onclick="showMenu()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Not quite. I want to hide menu and show button when screen is smaller than 850px. The button should than toggle between hiding and showing menu. if screen is resized larger than 850px the menu should always show and the button should be hidden.

Comment: check the updated snippet and click "full page" after running the code to check responsiveness. The updated snippet hides the menu on screens smaller than 850px and shows a button that you can toggle. - The menu shows by default on screens bigger than 850px. Double click issue is also resolved.